# AFNetworking fails to download large files

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

I'm currently trying to download some files with AFNetworking, for relative small files this seems to work, but I'm trying a slighter larger file (17MB) and it seems to just crash without any error.

The url is linking to a local file: http://test.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/test.pdf (I'm running it in the simulator, so this is accessible)

The only output I get is in the progress block

> progress: 0.009022

When I check the filesystem, it appears that the file is there, but only a few kb.

Is this a known error with AFNetworking, or maybe I'm just doing something wrong.

```
- (void)downloadIssue:(Issue *)issue
{
    NSString *fileName = [issue.pdf lastPathComponent];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:issue.pdf];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url] autorelease];
    NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:issue.pdf parameters:nil];

    AFURLConnectionOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"PDF DOWNLOAD COMPLETE");

        issue.pdf_location = filePath;

        // send out a notification with the issue
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PDF_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:issue forKey:@"issue"]];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"PDF DOWNLOAD FAILED");

    // send out a notification with the issue
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PDF_DOWNLOAD_FAILED" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:issue forKey:@"issue"]];
    }];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        float progress = (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;

        NSLog(@"progress: %f", progress);

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PDF_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: issue, @"issue", progress, @"progress", nil]];
    }];

    [_queue addOperation:operation];
}
```

Comment: what kinds of crash? is a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`? you tried Enable Zombie Object.

Comment: Well it could be a memory problem, you could try the [AFURLConnectionOperation](http://afnetworking.org/Documentation/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html) with the outstream propety set to a [file stream](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/WritingOutputStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002274-BAJCABBC). Also creating an `AFHTTPClient` instance and only using it to create the `NSURLRequest` for you is a bit over kill. The `AFHTTPClient` is meant as a REST api client, one instance shared by all calls.

Comment: @bitmapdata.com, it doesn't give much info, just Thread 1: signal SIGTRAP, I have Zombie Objects enabled.

Comment: I previously had a similar experience as you problem.  try again to remove the `postNotification` in `setDownloadPrgoressBlock`. and re-tried :). still not work?

Comment: @rckoenes, I just tried to use only one `AFHTTPClient` instance, but it has the same effect, smale files are ok to download, larget just seem to crash

Comment: @woutr_be my suggestion about `AFHTTPClient` had nothing to do the crash. It's just that the way you are using it is over kill. the `AFHTTPClient` has methods like: `–getPath:parameters:success:failure:`, `– postPath:parameters:success:failure:`, `–putPath:parameters:success:failure:` and `–deletePath:parameters:success:failure:` which take away the need to create you own operation and it to a queue. All is done by `AFHTTPClient `

Comment: @bitmapdata.com wow, that really helped, doesn't seem to give any problem now ... Is it because too many notifications are being send out? How do you keep track of the progress now in other classes?

Comment: @bitmapdata.com Or perhaps just sending the notification every 5%?

Comment: @rckoenes I see, I knew I was kinda using it wrong, so decided to change it anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I previously had a similar experience as you problem. Try to resolve this issue, it took over almost two weeks.

The same problem was with you. So I'm glad to finally meet you :)

Here is Solution.

if in downloadProgress block directly update UI, sometimes occur unknown error. because Ambiguous, but i think Main Thread crash. so, downloadProgress Block only update variable, execute timer update UI using a variable.

```
//At the same time download
myTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:processTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)
{
    //global ivar
    _progress = (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
}];

- (void)updateProgress:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    myProgressView.progress = _progress;
    if(fabs(1.f-_progress)<0.01f)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, that was a thought I had too, just create a timer and update it manually, another idea was to just update it every 5%.

But thanks a lot, don't think I would have figured this out myself