# AFNetworking fails to download file

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

Im trying to download files around 100 MB using the following code. My download progress block successfully shows the amount of bytes read and expected but the file does not seem to exist in the file system.

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.httpClient requestWithMethod:REQUEST_GET
                                                             path:@"" parameters:params];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:15];

AFURLConnectionOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];

[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    NordecaLog("read %d, total %lld, expected %lld ->", bytesRead , totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead);
    [self.delegate updateProgressWithBytesRead:totalBytesRead totalBytesExpected:totalBytesExpectedToRead];
}];
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)operation.response;
    int responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    NSString *md5CheckSum = [[httpResponse allHeaderFields]  objectForKey:@"MD5Checksum"];

    NordecaLog("MD 5 %@ ->", md5CheckSum);

    block(md5CheckSum, responseStatusCode, nil);
    NordecaLog("Success %i ->", responseStatusCode);
}];


[operation start];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003335/afnetworking-fails-to-download-large-files?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Manage to solve the problem. The file path I was creating dynamically seemed to be missing and therefore the library could not save the file.